# symfony 2 getting error class not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a mail class in symfony using swiftmailer. I have written mailer class as follow:

```
<?php
namespace Ens\NewBundle\Controller\Services;

class MyMailers
{

 public $setTovar='';


 public function setToloc($name)
 {
    $this->setTovar=$name;
 }

 public function mail()
 {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername('smtptest.hi@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('scientech');
        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject');
        $message->setFrom('ucerturohit@gmai.com');
        $message->setTo($this->setTovar);
        $message->setBody('Here is the message itself');
        $numSent = $mailer->send($message);
        return $numSent;
    }
}
```

and in `Notification.php` I have written code as follow:

```
//require_once('MyMailers.php');
use Ens\NewBundle\contrller\Services\MyMailers;
    function NotificationOnSignUp($z)
    {
    // echo $z;die;
         // $y=unserialize($z);
      echo $z;
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($z);
      echo "</pre>";
          $x=new MyMailers;
      $x->setToloc($z['to']);

          $z=$x->mail();
      if($z==1)
   $name='success';
  else
   $name='failed';
```

when I am running this code then I am getting the error :

`Fatal error: Class 'Ens\NewBundle\contrller\Services\MyMailers' not found in /var/www/Symfony/src/Ens/NewBundle/Controller/Services/Notification.php on line 13` what should I do ??

Comment: Typos? Ens\NewBundle\<<< contrller >>> \Services\MyMailers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$x=new \MyMailers;` will find in the global namespace.

What you should do is:

```
use Ens\NewBundle\Controller\Services\MyMailers as MyMailers;

$x = new MyMailers;
```

Comment: there is no effects after using this also

Comment: getting error `Fatal error: Class 'Ens\NewBundle\controller\Services\MyMailers' not found in /var/www/Symfony/src/Ens/NewBundle/Controller/Services/Notification.php on line 14 `

Comment: You should use `Ens\NewBundle\Controller\Services\MyMailers` not `Ens\NewBundle\controller\Services\MyMailers` Unix systems are case sensetive